# Why does LINQPad dump enum integer values as strings?

Tags: c#, linqpad

I was using LinqPad to test out some Enum functions and I didn't get integers like I expected when I used .Dump(). Why did the ToList() solve the problem?

```
void Main()
{
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(Options)).Cast<int>().Dump();
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(Options)).Cast<int>().ToList().Dump();
}

public enum  Options 
{
   Equal,
   LessThan,
   GreaterThan
}
```

[image]

Comment: i think this is a limitation of the `.Cast` operation. `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Options)).Cast<int>().Select(f => (int)f).Dump();` works for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, LINQPad is not the culprit here. This is because of an optimization in [`Enumerable.Cast`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#27bb217a6d5457ec):

```
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source) {
        IEnumerable<TResult> typedSource = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;
        if (typedSource != null) return typedSource;
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        return CastIterator<TResult>(source);
    }
```

As you can see, if `source` implements `IEnumerable<TResult>`, then `Cast` just returns the source unchanged. In this case, `source` is of type `Option[]`, which happens to implement `IEnumerable<int>`, so `Cast` returns an array of `Option`, and LINQPad dumps it.

I must admit that it came as a surprise that `Option[]` can be cast to `IEnumerable<int>`, but it seems to be the case...

Comment: It can't just be cast to `IEnumerable<int>` - it can be cast to `int[]`! This is a conversion that the CLR allows, but the C# language doesn't... so to make the cast compile, you have to confuse the C# compiler by converting to `object` first... but then it works fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I assume that it works only because the underlying type of that enum is int?

Comment: Yup. Although you could cast to `uint[]` as well. The CLR is quite forgiving when it comes to conversions like that.